# Error in filling dataset with oledb

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am getting

> "No value given for one and more required parameter"

from below code everything looks fine not able to find the problem.

```
 string myConnectionString= @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=D:\TiptonDB.mdb";
                string query = "SELECT NodeID FROM NDDINodes";//"SELECT O.NodeID, N.NodeID FROM NDDINodes AS N, NDDINodes AS O WHERE N.X=O.X And N.Y=O.Y And N.NodeID<>O.NodeID";

                DataSet dt = new DataSet();
                using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection())
                {
                    myConnection.ConnectionString=myConnectionString;
                    OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand ();
                    cmd.Connection=myConnection;

                 //   cmd.CommandText="SELECT O.NodeID, N.NodeID FROM NDDINodes AS N, NDDINodes AS O WHERE N.X=O.X And N.Y=O.Y And N.NodeID<>O.NodeID";
                    myConnection.Open();
                    OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(query,myConnection);
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                }
```

Comment: You might have misspelled table name or column name.Check this !!

Comment: Is `NodeID` existent in table `NDDINodes`?
Is the table `NDDINodes` existent?

Comment: You never actually execute the code. Don't you need to executequery or before passing it to a dataset. You don't even open the connection.

Comment: @DaveRook Do we need to execute query in case of OleDbDataAdapter class ?

Comment: Run this query in access database query editor and check if it showing any error there ?

Comment: Where does the error trigger?

Comment: @RajeevKumar, I can't test it so good point, I am used to SQL. Shrivallabh please check out this [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as it may help  (scroll to bottom of page)

Comment: @RajeevKumar i tested in query editor its working fine

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your code

```
  OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter();
ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myConnectionString= @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=D:\TiptonDB.mdb";
                string query = "SELECT NodeID FROM NDDINodes";//"SELECT O.NodeID, N.NodeID FROM NDDINodes AS N, NDDINodes AS O WHERE N.X=O.X And N.Y=O.Y And N.NodeID<>O.NodeID";

DataSet dt = new DataSet();

OleDbConnection objXConn = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);
                objXConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, objXConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand);
                adp.Fill(dt);
                objXConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string isn't missing data: `UserName/Password`, `Persist Security Info=True`,...

[Check this link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) for access connectionString settings.